# Websockets ws - Node & Express - export API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, websocket

I got successfully my websocket up and running but I need to use the `.send()` method on my route.

I got my app split on several files. In this case I got:

**app.js**

```
//..some other code..

//Server

const server = http.createServer(app)
var port = process.env.PORT || 80;
const connection = server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on ' + port);
});


const WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;
const wss = new WebSocketServer({
  server
});

//Here I need to export the wss

module.exports.sengMsg = function (msg, callback) {
  return wss.on("connection", function (ws) {

    ws.send(msg, callback);


    ws.on("close", function () {
      console.log("websocket connection close")
    })
  })
};
```

**api.js**

```
//..some other code..

var sendMsg = require('../app').sendMsg;


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    sendMsg('Hi I from default route', (err)=>{
       console.log("I got some error on ws");
    })
    res.send('Welcome to my API');

})
```

But in the end I come up with

> TypeError: sendMsg is not a function

What is the recommended way to export the funcionality of my `wss` on my routes using this setup ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the code to,

```
var sendMsg = require('./app');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
   sendMsg.sendMsg('Hi I from default route', (err)=>{
   console.log("I got some error on ws");
   })
   res.send('Welcome to my API');

})
```

or change the app.js module.exports to following,

```
module.exports = {
sendMessage :function (msg, callback) {
    return wss.on("connection", function (ws) {

        ws.send(msg, callback);


        ws.on("close", function () {
            console.log("websocket connection close")
        })
    })
}
}
```

Comment: As the edited code try removing one of the dots in the require statement

Comment: @Korte did you try the solution ?

Comment: Yes it didn't work. I've come up with an other workaround makin use of `eventEmitters`